# Creating Windows PE boot cd with MyDefrag

Tags: windows-7, windows-pe, mydefrag

As I would like to defrag the unmovable files. As far as I understend it is possible to do by running Windows PE. What is the easiest way of creating custom Windows PE image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 PE boot disc. Similar to BartPE but allows for x64 booting as well as booting directly from the .iso using Multiboot.

[Win7PE_SE](http://reboot.pro/12427/)

Comment: while links are useful, explaining what this link is, would be doubly useful. should the link die, at the very least future users of the site would know what's happening.

Comment: Hmm. It complain I haven't installes WIMP despite I had installed it...

Comment: @ Maciej, I did not install anything, what I did was have the conents of my Windows 7 dvd at C:\Folder, then download the project which is just WinBuilder with some scripts ... then run winbuilder, set the path to Windows 7 and then fire it off.

Comment: It does not accept WIMP - it requires DVD.